# C# How can I merge two Bitmaps?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, merge

I'm trying to find a way to merge two Bitmaps together in a Paint event. My code looks like this:

```
private void GraphicsForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap1 = new Bitmap(1366, 768);
        Bitmap2 = new Bitmap(1366, 768);
        OutputBitmap = ...//and this is where I've stuck :(
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is more problematic, because the Graphics object which draws onto Bitmap2 is in an other class.
I also want Bitmap2 to be drawn behind Bitmap1 on the OutputBitmap.

Can anyone give me a good advice how to merge these two Bitmaps (behind eachother, but) onto one output bitmap?

Thanks :)

Comment: not sure what you're asking. Do you just want to add the color values of each pixel together?

Comment: a) Sorry but i can't understand your *problematic* case. b) What do you mean by *merging*. How do you merge two colors for example.

Comment: Are you trying to actually create a single bitmap to save or just paint 2 bitmaps on a form? If it's the latter, it may be faster to just paint each bitmap in the order you want.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your bitmaps have transparent areas, try creating one bitmap and draw the other two bitmaps into it in the order you want:

```
private Bitmap MergedBitmaps(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
  Bitmap result = new Bitmap(Math.Max(bmp1.Width, bmp2.Width),
                             Math.Max(bmp1.Height, bmp2.Height));
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
    g.DrawImage(bmp2, Point.Empty);
    g.DrawImage(bmp1, Point.Empty);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: How does this *merge* two images? `A OR B` `A AND B` `A XOR B` `(A+B)/2` etc?

Comment: @L.B I'm reading the post as the OP just wants one bitmap from the two that they have.  I'm not interpreting that any *blending* is required.

Comment: Does this preserve transparency in the resulting image ?

Comment: @GillesjrBisson As long as the used bitmaps have transparencies, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Bitmap Combine(params Bitmap[] sources)
    {
        List<int> imageHeights = new List<int>();
        List<int> imageWidths = new List<int>();
        foreach (Bitmap img in sources)
        {
            imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
            imageWidths.Add(img.Width);
        }
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(imageWidths.Max(), imageHeights.Max());
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            foreach (Bitmap img in sources)
                g.DrawImage(img, Point.Empty);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Enjoy...