# Stitch together grid of images of equal size

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I have a grid of 26 by 13 images each being 512px by 512px. All are .jpgs. Is there a library or simple way to stitch these images together into one large .jpg file? I've had a look and only found libraries that are overly complex for what I need to do.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I found the solution to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182016/9819256).

Comment: You can do it in matlab  : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/176476-merging-multiple-jpg-files-into-a-single-image

Comment: You'll need to write some positioning code yourself and determine the size of the resulting bitmap in advance, but otherwise, yes, the linked `g.DrawImage` method will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with some fairly simple code

```
        using (Bitmap result = new Bitmap(26 * 512, 13 * 512))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 13; y++)
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                        g.DrawImage(images[x, y], x * 512, y * 512);
            result.Save(file, format);
        }
```